# Email greetings: hi <name> vs dear <name> vs hi dear <name>

Tags: email, greetings

I am not sure what is the right way to be a bit informal in an email. When students call a professor or a staff by the first name, I believe greetings in an email can be a bit casual.
I believe the most formal way to call a professor is `Dear Prof. <family name>` and for a staff, I believe it would be `Dear \<first nam> \<last name>`.
But when it comes to a less formal way, there are lots of possibilities. I am not sure which ones are appropriate and which are not. Can you please tell me which of these are informal but still respectful?

> 1 Dear <first name>

> 2 Hi dear Professor or Hello dear Professor

> 3 Hi Prof. <last name> or Hello Prof. <last name>

> 4 Hi <first name> or Hello <fist name>

> 5 Hi dear <first name> or Hello dear <fist name>

> 6 Hi dear Prof. <last name>

Comment: I work in a UK legal office, and we had a temp from an agency who, we found, was emailing judges starting 'Hi Judge'. An older, senior, male judge complained about her not using appropriate form of address. She said, not unreasonably, that most judges responded 'Hi Dani'. Your options 2 to 6 are either informal or just strange. So play safe and use option 1 only.

Comment: "Dear X" is the standard way to begin a letter, but it should _-not_  be combined with another greeting unless you are intending to express affection for the recipient. "Hello, dear Professor" implies that the professor is literally dear to you.

Comment: I don't believe I have _ever, ever, ever_ started an email with _Dear (anybody)_. That is a convention of traditional letters (still), that as far as I am concerned, has never been transferred to email.

Comment: @ColinFine - Dear Judge, Dear Mr Jones, Dear Bill, all pretty common where I work, also just the title and surname e.g. Judge Jones, Ms Panesar, or even just the first name alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to Colin (in comments) I often start emails with "Dear", especially when I am not replying, and certainly if the person is not someone I interact with all the time.

For example, writing to the school exam secretary:

> Dear Katie,
>
> We've decided to use the week of ....

Writing to a parent

> Dear Ms Price,
>
> I pleased to report that...

Writing a group email to my class:

> Dear all,
>
> The homework this week will be...

On the other hand when writing to teachers in my own department (that I work closely with)

> Good morning Clare,
>
> Can we meet to talk about...

> Hello Joe, Louis,
>
> Can I ask a favour...

When replying to an internal email I don't write any salutation. I just respond directly

Replying to the exam secretary:

> Yes, that's a good idea....

Replying to another teacher asking about a student:

> As of 4th March, Oliver is ....

(actual examples from my emails, but names and details have been changed)

General advice:  If not sure, start "Dear". Nobody will complain and it is quite normal.  When replying internally you don't need any salutation. But I would still use on when writing externally.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Could you provide source for the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

2, 5 and 6 are not professional or natural-sounding, and I wouldn't use them in an informal way either, they have an odd and foreign feeling to me as a native speaker.

3(Using hello, not hi) has an appropriate balance of informal and respectful, although that really depends on the person's status.